# SharePoint user not found in the directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, login

I am new to SharePoint and I have a problem with a user who cannot log in. The error message is: "The user was not found in the directory"

It is an Office 365 SharePoint Online. I have added the user to the member group and he has a windows live id.

Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message shows the external user hasn’t been authenticated successfully. You can do the following steps to check if the problem persists:

1. Click Site settings > Site permissions > click on any group such as Members group.
2. On the selected group page, note the URL, change the number after the “=” to a “0″, then hit enter.

[image]

3. A screen displaying all people will appear. In this final screen, check if you can find the login the user that receives the login issue. If yes, delete the user then resend the invite and test the result.

Comment: What if I have the same issue, but user is **not** in that list?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 404 answer - if does not help - install SharePoint Online powershell and use this PS script (replace 'portal' with Your tenant):

```
$creds = Get-Credential

Connect-SPOService -Url https://portal-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $cred

$ExtUser = Get-SPOExternalUser -filter Will.Smith@portal.com
Remove-SPOExternalUser -UniqueIDs @($ExtUser.UniqueId)
```